# Fixing pug syntax highlighting

Tags: syntax-highlighting, colorscheme

**Update**
I've managed to get the top part of the file fixed with `syn region pugJavascriptLine start=/^\s*-/ end=/$/ contains=@htmlJavascript` from this programmer: https://github.com/digitaltoad/vim-pug/issues/98#issuecomment-296461439

But the template strings still don't recognize their contents as JavaScript:

[image]

Perhaps there's another line I could add to the pug syntax file that would let it know how template strings work. The file is here: https://github.com/digitaltoad/vim-pug/blob/master/syntax/pug.vim

Anyone with better Regex skills than me out there?

**Update end**

I'm using neovim for lots of web dev, and I'm having trouble with pug syntax highlighting.

I can't seem to get it to display JavaScript in the pug files (which it was doing just fine before I switched to a new Thinkpad).

[image]

The JS is just in plain white text. Here's my vimrc: https://gist.github.com/wamoyo/34405c4672c89dbfded62ea34134003b

And I haven't edited the pug.vim file or anything like that. But I have messed around a bit with the xoria256.vim colorscheme file, adding this to the bottom:

```
" hi jsBooleanTrue ctermfg=41
" hi jsBooleanFalse ctermfg=174
" hi jsString ctermfg=229
" hi jsComment ctermfg=244
hi jsGlobalObjects ctermfg=256
hi jsGlobalNodeObjects ctermfg=256
" hi jsExceptions ctermfg=256
" hi jsThis ctermfg=256
" hi jsPrototype ctermfg=256
" hi jsHtmlEvents ctermfg=256
" hi jsDecorator ctermfg=146
" hi jsSpecial ctermfg=180
" hi jsFloat ctermfg=180
" hi jsNan ctermfg=180
" hi jsTemplateVar ctermfg=251
" hi jsTemplateBraces ctermfg=146
" hi jsDecoratorFunction ctermfg=182
" hi jsRegexpString ctermfg=180
" hi jsRegexpBoundary ctermfg=180
" hi jsRegexpQuantifier ctermfg=180
" hi jsRegexpOr ctermfg=180
" hi jsRegexpMod ctermfg=180
" hi jsRegexpBackRef ctermfg=180
" hi jsRegexpGroup ctermfg=180
" hi jsRegexpCharClass ctermfg=180
```

On the old laptop, I didn't have any of those commented out, but the new laptop seems to support more colors in the gnome terminal.

This line from `pug.vim` seems relevant:

```
syn region pugJavascript matchgroup=pugJavascriptChar start="-" skip=",\s*$" end="$" contained contains=@htmlJavascript keepend
```

Lines 6-16 above are using the syntax group `pugTagInlineText`.

Actually, I know it's not those edits in the xoria256.vim file, because I have the same issue with other colorschemes.

I'm also happy to switch colorschemes if there's one that handles html5, css, and ES6 really nicely.

Comment: Can you check the syntax highlighting groups in the lines you think are being incorrectly highlighted? (There are various tips for doing this across the web; my plugin [synstax](https://github.com/benknoble/vim-synstax) can also do it.)

Comment: Hm.. trying. They are lines 6 to 16 above.

Comment: I tried making changes to pug.vim, but no changes take effect, even after restarting vim. If I can't make changes, maybe something set up wrong?

Comment: That does seem odd, but what will be most telling is still the highlight groups being applied to text in those lines.

Comment: It's ['PugBegin'], problem is that's the same for every line I've checked.

Comment: Scratch that, column matters. So... ['pugTagInlineText'], which is not what it should be. It should be embeded JavaScript or something like that.

Comment: Seems this line in the pug.vim file might be relevant... `syn region  pugJavascript matchgroup=pugJavascriptChar start="-" skip=",\s*$" end="$" contained contains=@htmlJavascript keepend`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is solved. It took a couple lines in the pug syntax file.

Adding the third line here for template strings:

```
syn region  pugJavascriptString start=+"+  skip=+\\\("\|$\)+  end=+"\|$+ contained
syn region  pugJavascriptString start=+'+  skip=+\\\('\|$\)+  end=+'\|$+ contained
" TODO my patch for template strings
syn region  pugJavascriptString start=+`+  skip=+\\\(`\|$\)+  end=+`\|$+ contained
```

And the single line for single lines of JS: `syn region pugJavascriptLine start=/^\s*-/ end=/$/ contains=@htmlJavascript`

Github issues here: https://github.com/digitaltoad/vim-pug/issues/109
and here: https://github.com/digitaltoad/vim-pug/issues/108